# Can't read [/Users/vannadal/Documents/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.1.0/multidex/shrinkedAndroid.jar] (No such file or directory)

Tags: android-studio

Everything is ok before.However when I add  several external jars and run the project,the error is coming.The apk can build seccessfully.Im a new android studio user.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [/Users/vannadal/Documents/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.1.0/multidex/shrinkedAndroid.jar] (No such file or directory)

the following is build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vannadal.promotion.promotionalarm"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happened to me too, try deleting this line "multiDexEnabled true" and cleaning the project

Comment: This is not a solution for projects exceeding 64K dex files. They have to use multiDexEnabled:true

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle build tools version in top level build.gradle and change it to latest `1.5.0`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set my buildToolsVersion 23.0.1 solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your app/build.gradle

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
}
```

Or use a later build tool version.

Removing `multiDexEnabled:true` is NOT a solution for the projects exceeding 64K dex file. They have to use it.